# rails why model new().save doesn't work in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, scaffold

In Model-1 scaffold create action,

```
 def create
  @auclub = Auclub.new(auclub_params)
  user = User.find(current_user.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @auclub.save && user.update(auclub_id: @auclub.id)
      format.html { redirect_to @auclub, notice: 'Auclub was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @auclub }
    else
       //some codes
    end
  end
end
```

and and i want create club with user

this code works, but if i use like this

```
user = User.find(current_user.id)
user.new(auclub_id : @auclub.id)
user.save
```

it doesn't works! is there any differences between update and new.save?

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
  @auclub = Auclub.new(auclub_params)
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @auclub.save
  @user.auclub_id = @auclub.id
  @user.save
```

Know more [APi dock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/save)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing things in a wrong way.

Without model and other codes, I can suggest to do like this:

```
user = User.find(current_user.id)
user.auclub_id = @auclub.id
user.save
```

And I think there is no `new` method available for an ActiveRecord instance like `user` in your case.

`new` is used on ActiveRecord class to create a new instance like:

```
user = User.new
```

And I don't think there is much difference between using `update` method and manually reassigning an attribute and saving the object using `save` method but you have to keep an eye on performance, DRY principle and callbacks defined on model.